# Any No Root Firewalls, from Major Security Vendors?

Tags: firewall

This question is "only" concerning no root firewalls, which are currently available from Major Security Vendors (such as Symantec, Comodo, Avast, McAfee, etc...) AND which can filter based on DNS/host name, ip subnet and ip addresses.  Also, the firewall must work on Android OS 4.4, or later.

Does anyone know of any such firewall products?

If not, you can answer the following related question instead.  Does it appear that it is not possible to have a good Android OS 4.4+ firewall, without root access (at least with the current Android OS)?

Comment: I don't know any and I don't think that this is actually technically feasible witout root.

Comment: A good firewall needs root access to monitor the network traffic and filter out incoming and outgoing connections based on rules. A normal user can only restrict network access for the user he is running an application as (see how users/user ids are working in any good linux wiki).